# Not being able to center this div in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i'm having some problem to center this div in wp.
[image: img]

This booking.com widget is inside the div class, the container i assume.

```
.et_pb_widget_area .et_pb_widget_area_left .clearfix et_pb_module 
.et_pb_bg_layout_light  .et_pb_sidebar_0 .et_pb_sidebar_no_border
```

That is from Divi Theme Builder. His dimensions are 1036 x 341.188;

Tried to put margin: 0 auto in the booking.com class that is(dimensions 362.594 x 284.219):

```
.et_pb_widget bos_searchbox_widget_class
```

But no success. I also tried setting max width: 100% to the container and margin: 0 auto; to the search box but also no success.

If needed, its the plugin Booking.com Official Search Box.

Also, this is the website i'm trying to center this: http://198.199.66.183/

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot in your CSS, tested and it seems to work:

```
.et_pb_sidebar_0.et_pb_widget_area .et_pb_widget{
    width: 35%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
```

Expected outcome:
[image]

Code was edited with the live inspector in chrome, here's the code inside the inspector and which element I selected to get this to work:

[image]

Hope this helps! Good luck!